# one table minus another

Tags: sql

I am not sure on how to do this.
I have three tables members table with 238871 members
                    jobs table with 7713 entries
                    trade table and with 231142 entries

if i take 238871 members minus what is in the trade table i get a difference of 7729. in the jobs table I have 7713 entries so there are 16 unaccounted for in the members table. all of trade is in jobs and members tables. but in members there a 16 that is not in jobs and trade.

How can I define those 16 members?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a `left join` gives you *everything* in `jobsortedusers`. Then everything in `members` that is also in `jobsortedusers`.

It sounds like you either want to reverse the order of your left outer join and do this instead:

```
select * 
  from membership.members as mm
  left outer join jobsorted.jobsortedusers as js
    on mm.memberid = js.memberid
```

This gets you everything in `members` and then everything in `jobsortedusers` that is also in `members`. As you say that every user is also a member this query returns you everything.

I can highly recommend reading [this, which explains joins very well](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

---

To answer your new question you want everything where the `jobsortedusers` id is null, i.e.

```
select mm.* -- every other column will be null
  from membership.members as mm
  left outer join jobsorted.jobsortedusers as js
    on mm.memberid = js.memberid
 where js.memberid is null
```

I don't know what to join `trade` on but in order to get everything that is not in either this table or your users table you need something like this:

```
select mm.* -- every other column will be null 
  from membership.members as mm
  left outer join jobsorted.jobsortedusers as js
    on mm.memberid = js.memberid
  left outer join trade t
    on mm.memberid = t.memberid
 where js.memberid is null
   and t.memberid is null
```

Comment: the second query gives me the unaccounted members of 16, is exactly what I need, thanks